# Using JSON data returned from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a jquery ajax function that works just fine in going out and retrieving data. What I'm experiencing though is that I cannot seem to pull individual json data elements from the returned data using, what I thought was, conventional methods.

```
$("a[name$='-test']").click(function() {
  var rpc_url = '/history/get_test/' + $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
         url : rpc_url,
        type : 'post',
 contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype : 'json',
     success : function(data) {
       console.log(data.id);
    }
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data.title);
  });
});
```

}

Original resulting data was formatted like this;

```
[{"id":"1","title":"Test title"}]
```

Then I modified my remote code to just return the data outside of an array context as such;

```
{"id":"1","title":"Test title"}
```

As you can see in my code, I tried accessing the data both at the success event and at the done event. Fiddler shows well formatted json as the returned data. Though both continue to yield undefined in the console output for `data.id` & `data.title`.

So, am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you need to JSONDecode it before accessing it this way. (i guess)

Comment: Delete your `contentType:` setting, which describes *sent* data, not the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try dataType:'json' instead of datatype:'json' ^^

Comment: LMAO!!! I so missed that! Yeah, that was it, alright! Thank you so much for catching that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the data first like this:

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

`datatype` changed to `dataType`

if not evaluate to JSON Object, you need to convert to `Object` manually, so you should do something like this:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(data)["title"])
```